# Question regarding elementary distribution theory

Tags: indefinite-integrals, distribution-theory

Let $D'(I)$ be the space of distributions on an open interval $I$, and let $D(I)$ be the space of test functions on $I$.

I got the following homework assignment:

"Define $u\in D'(\mathbb{R})$ be defined through 
$\left\langle u,\phi\right\rangle=-\int_{0}^{\infty}\ln(t)\phi'(t)dt$ for $\phi\in D(\mathbb{R})$. Determine a function $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ such that $u=f$ on $(-\infty,0)$ and on $(0,\infty)$. Is it meaningful to ask if $u=f$ on $\mathbb{R}?$"

When trying to do this I used

$\left\langle u,\phi\right\rangle=-\int_{0}^{\infty}\ln(t)\phi'(t)dt=/\text{Partial integration}/=-\left[\ln(t)\phi(t)\right]_0^{\infty}+\int_0^{\infty}\frac{1}{t}\phi(t)dt$,

but here I got a bit stuck, and I don't know how to move on. The answers sheet says:

"For example $f(t)=\frac{1}{t}$ for $t>0$, and $f(t)=0$ for $t\leq 0$; No, it's not useful, since $f$ is not locally integrable on $\mathbb{R}$".

But then I get when I calculate:

$\left\langle u,\phi\right\rangle=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(t)\phi(t)dt=\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{t}\phi(t)dt=\left[\ln(t)\phi(t)\right]_0^{\infty}-\int_{0}^{\infty}\ln(t)\phi'(t)dt$.

Are they somehow saying that $\left[\ln(t)\phi(t)\right]_0^{\infty}=0$? Why is that? I get what they mean by $f$ not being locally integrable on $\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Roll back to the definition of a distribution. If we say that $u=f$ on $(-\infty,0)$ and on $(0,+\infty)$, it means for any test function $\phi$ with support in $(-\infty,0)\cup(0,+\infty)$ you have $$\langle u,\phi\rangle=\int_{-\infty}^0 f(t)\phi(t)dt + \int_0^{\infty} f(t)\phi(t)dt.$$ Now, by taking into account the support of $\phi$, you can conclude that, indeed, $\lim_{x\to +0}\ln (t) \phi(t) = \lim_{x\to +\infty}\ln (t) \phi(t)=0$ and hence the choice of $f$ from your textbook fits.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I kind of realized that a test function would have a support that would be a compact set, but it took me way too long to see why this would be enough to ensure the limits above.